# Split the numbers in a different range

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am trying to measure how much time each thread takes in inserting to database. I have captured all those performance numbers in a `ConcurrentHashMap` named map like how much time each thread is taking in inserting. In that concurrent hash map it will be something like this.

```
Key- 10
Value- 2
```

So that means, 2 Calls came back in 10 ms. Another example below

```
Key - 20
Value -1
```

which means, 1 Call came back in 20 ms.

And that map will contain lot more data means lot more key value pair.

So now I am trying to do something like below by using the same map above, that means I need to iterate the above map to get the below numbers in that particular range. Is that possible to do?

```
How many calls(X number) came back in between 1 and 20 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 20 and 40 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 40 and 60 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 60 and 80 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 80 and 100 ms
How many calls(X number) came back after 100 ms
```

Some code that I thought of initially.

```
SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(map.keySet());
for (Long key : keys) {
    System.out.print(key + " : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < map.get(key); i++) {
                 // Not sure what I am supposed to do here?
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Can anyone help me here?

**Update:-**

My map sample value-

```
{31=3, 48=1, 33=1, 30=12, 43=1, 38=1, 32=1}
```

It means total call was `3+1+1+12+1+1+1 = 20` by adding `value` from the `map`

And out of that I need to figure out the above scenario means something like this

```
How many calls(X number) came back in between 1 and 20 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 20 and 40 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 40 and 60 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 60 and 80 ms
How many calls(X number) came back in between 80 and 100 ms
How many calls(X number) came back after 100 ms
```

Below is my code that I have tried with the below suggestion-

private static void drawHistogram(Map map) {

```
int counter[] = new int[6];

for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("" + key);    

    // add sample
    int idx = key / 20;
    idx = Math.min(idx, counter.length - 1);
    counter[idx]++;
    }

for (int i = 0; i < counter.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(counter[i] + " came back in between " + i * 20 + " and " + (i + 1) * 20
            + " ms");
}
```

}

As you can see, I have 20 calls made but this is showing only 7 calls. Anything wrong I did? This is the output I got-

```
0 came back in between 0 and 20 ms
5 came back in between 20 and 40 ms
2 came back in between 40 and 60 ms
0 came back in between 60 and 80 ms
0 came back in between 80 and 100 ms
0 came back in between 100 and 120 ms
```

which shows only 7 calls. But there are 20 calls.

Comment: Don't vote to close this - OP is reasonably asking what data structure to use for a specific, understandable problem

Comment: Are you trying to print histogram ?

Comment: just change concurrenthashmap to concurrentskiplistmap which is a navigable map and offers a rich api to perform range based queries; my answer has the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anticipating the need to easily redefine bucket size (and indeed the number of buckets you aggregate into) I propose:

```
    Map<Integer, Integer> values = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int[] definition = {0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100};
    int[] buckets = new int[definition.length];

    for (int time : values.keySet()) {
        for (int i=definition.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if (time >= definition[i]) {
                buckets[i] += values.get(time);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<definition.length; i++) {
        String period = "";
        if (i == definition.length-1) {
            period = "greater than " + definition[i] + "ms";
        } else {
            period = "between " +
                      (definition[i]+1) +
                      " and " +
                      definition[i+1] + "ms";
        }
        System.out.println(buckets[i] + " came back " + period);
    }
```

Configurability is managed by changing `definition`. I used the following code to test this:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        int time = rnd.nextInt(121);
        Integer calls = values.get(time);
        if (calls == null) {
            calls = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
        calls += 1;
        values.put(time, calls);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the help. Definitely your code has cofigurability. The only difficulty I am facing is you are generating Random number. In my case I have already those numbers in the hash map. I have updated the question with more detail. I am trying to modify your suggestion to work with map as well but having hard time in figuring out.

Comment: Ugh! Sorry I misread your question - I'll update so it works properly.  Give me a few minutes :)

Comment: @FarhanJamal: OK, fixed. Sorry about my confusion.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the help. Works like a charm.

Comment: I needed your help in one of my other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786183/single-thread-writing-to-different-database-with-different-connection-parameters). I believe you can provide me a solution that can be configurable as that particular problem requires extensibility and configurability. Whenever you have some time, let me know what approach should I take in that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(map.keySet());
Map<Long, Long> values = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
Integer total = null;
Integer current = null;
Long point = null;
for (Long key : keys) {
    System.out.print(key + " : ");
    current = map.get(key);
    if(key >= 1 && key <= 20) {
        point = 1;
    } // Do Other Comparisons also and change point 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

    total = values.get(point);
    if(total == null) {
        total = 0;
    }
    total += current;
    values.put(point, total);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now if you loop throw the `keySet` of `values`

Point 1 will be `How many calls(X number) came back in between 1 and 20 ms`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `NavigableMap` which allows you to query a range of numbers (head, tail).
A thread safe implementation is `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

In particular look the the methods `NavigableMap<K,V> headMap(K toKey, boolean inclusive)`, `NavigableMap<K,V> tailMap(K fromKey, boolean inclusive)` and `SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)`

Example

```
//your existing concurrent map changed to concurrent navigable map
NavigableMap<Long, Long> throughputCounter = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, Long>();
            // this prints for inclusive values - 1 and 20 are both included
            System.out.println("How many calls(X number) came back in between 1 and 20 ms:" + calcThroughput(throughputCounter.subMap(1L, true, 20L, true)));
            System.out.println("How many calls(X number) came back in between 20 and 40 ms:" + calcThroughput(throughputCounter.subMap(20L, true, 40L, true)));
            System.out.println("How many calls(X number) came back in between 40 and 60 ms:" + calcThroughput(throughputCounter.subMap(40L, true, 60L, true)));
            System.out.println("How many calls(X number) came back in between 60 and 80 ms:" + calcThroughput(throughputCounter.subMap(60L, true, 80L, true)));
            System.out.println("How many calls(X number) came back in between 80 and 100 ms:" + calcThroughput(throughputCounter.subMap(80L, true, 100L, true)));
            System.out.println("How many calls(X number) came back in after 100 ms:" + calcThroughput(throughputCounter.tailMap(100L)));

    private Long calcThroughput(NavigableMap<Long, Long> subMap) {
        Long sumOfARange = new Long(0);
        for (Long value : subMap.values()) {
            sumOfARange += value;
        }
        return sumOfARange;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Scorpion for the suggestion. I haven't worked with NavigableMap before. How I will be calling calcThroughput method here? Got little bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a map at all. You could simply divide the time by 20 (ms) and increment a counter in an array.

```
public static void main( String[] args) {
    int counter[] = new int[6];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {
        int time = (int) ( Math.random() * 200 );
        System.out.println( "" + time  );
        // add sample
        int idx = time / 20;
        idx = Math.min( idx, counter.length-1);
        counter[idx]++;
    }

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < counter.length ; i++ ) {
        System.out.println( counter[i] + " came back in between " + i*20 + " and " + (i+1)*20 + " ms" );
    }
}
```

Please note that the last array element holds the number of all samples >= 100ms, thus the output should be corrected. Omitted to make the code as short and clear as possible.

Example output

```
13 came back in between 0 and 20 ms
10 came back in between 20 and 40 ms
13 came back in between 40 and 60 ms
10 came back in between 60 and 80 ms
11 came back in between 80 and 100 ms
43 came back in between 100 and 120 ms
```

UPDATE:
    The output as it should be

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < counter.length-1 ; i++ ) {
    System.out.println( counter[i] + " came back in between " + i*20 + " and " + (i+1)*20 + " ms" );
}
System.out.println( counter[counter.length-1] + " came back after 100" ms" );
```

Comment: Thanks stacker for the suggestion. I am using Map to store those numbers in the run method of multithreaded code. So that is the reason Map came into the picture. And then I will be using that Map to do the way you suggested me out.

Comment: @FarhanJamal You could also synchronize the array access: -`synchronized ( counter ) {
                counter[idx]++;
            }`

Comment: Yeah. I agree. I tried your suggestion and it looks more cleaner. Only thing that I am can see missing is in the last line of your output, you are showing `43 came back in between 100 and 120 ms`. Instead of that is there any way to show `X came back in greater than 100 ms`? Because there will be thousands of numbers. So that is the reason I was trying to simplify it till 100.

Comment: @FarhanJamal Yes, you only need to loop from index 0..5 to print 'between lines' and print the 6th item with another text ('greater than').

Comment: I think, I messed up my code as I am using Map in my code. So something gone wrong. I have updated the question with my code example.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
SortedSet<Long> keys = new TreeSet<Long>(map.keySet());

int group1To20=0;
int group20To40=0;
int group40To60=0;
int group60To80=0;
int group80To100=0;
int groupAbove100=0;
for (Long key : keys) {
 if(key>=0 && key<=20){
  group1To20=group1To20+map.get(key);
  }elseif(key>20 && key<=40){
   group20To40=group20To40+map.get(key);
  }
 //Similarly do as above for other range of group

}//end of loop


System.out.print("group 1-20 contains " +  group1To20);
//Now print the group range and values here

}
```

I have tried for your solution. I may misunderstand your question. If so, then clearify the question for me.