# Single thread writing to different database with different connection parameters

Tags: java, database, jdbc, performance

I am working on a project in which I have three tables in a different database with different schemas. So that means I have three different connection parameters for those three tables to connect using JDBC-

Let's suppose-

**For Table1-**

```
Username:- A
Password:- B
URL:       C

Columns-
ID1         String
Account1    String
```

**For Table2-**

```
Username:- P
Password:- Q
URL:-      R

Columns-
ID2         String
Account2    String
```

**For Table3-**

```
Username:- T
Password:- U
URL:-      V

Columns-
ID3         String
Account3    String
```

And I am supposed to insert in all the three tables or any one of them using JDBC.

Below are the three use cases I have-

> 1. From the command prompt if suppose I am passing Table1 only, then I am suppose to insert only in Table1 columns by making connection to
>      Table1.
> 2. And if I am passing Table1, Table2 from the command prompt then I am suppose to insert in both Table1 and Table2 columns by making
>      connection to Table1 and Table2.
> 3. And if I am passing Table1, Table2 and Table3 then I am suppose to enter in all the three tables using there respective connection
>      parameter

I am not able to understand how to write code for the above particular scenario in such a cleaner way so that it can be extended in near future as well if I come up with four tables. I can have a one constant file which can store the SQL that needs to be executed for any of the three tables and some other constant thing as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


}


 class Task implements Runnable {

    private Connection dbConnection = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    public Task() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

    dbConnection = getDbConnection();

    //prepare the statement and execute it

    }
  }


    private Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

          Class.forName(Constants.DRIVER_NAME);
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection( , , );

      return dbConnection;
    }
```

Can anyone provide some thoughts on this how should I proceed forward?

**Note:-**

Column in each table will differ a lot. Like in some tables, column can be 10 and in some other table, column can be 20.

Comment: What is the purpose of the threading as opposed to just inserting into the three tables one by one from a single thread? Is there a lot of data to insert so you want to parallellize?

Comment: Yeah we are planning to do Load and Performance testing on our new database. So we will be running lots of thread and will be putting lots of load on our new database. So that is the whole reason of doing it. And yes there will be lot of data and I want to parallelize.

Comment: If someone enters `Table1` , `Table2` and `Table3` as command line , the insertion in tables will take place in three separate threads in parallel ?

Comment: I was thinking of using a single thread to insert into three tables simultaneously. And if I have 10 threads then all the 10 thread will be inserting into three tables simultaneously.

Comment: Basically I wanted to put a load on database. So I thought if I am using single thread to insert into multiple tables which can put some load on that.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. Thanks for the help. I was wondering how will I be putting that in a Multithreaded code?

Comment: If you clarify your requirement with more elaboration then I could assist you better..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24254/discussion-between-farhan-jamal-and-vishal-k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `databases.properties` file with content like this:

```
# Table 1
table1.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
table1.user: gardener
table1.password: shavel
table1.table: fruits
table1.column.id: fruitID
table1.column.color: fruitColor
table1.column.weight: fruitWeight
# ... More fruit columns here ...

# Table 2
table2.url: jdbc:mysql://otherhost:3306/forest
table2.user: forester
table2.password: axe
table2.table: trees
table2.column.id: treeID
table2.column.height: treeHeight
# ... More tree columns here ...

# ... More tables here ...
```

Then do something like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Properties databasesProperties = new Properties ();
    databasesProperties.load ("databases.properties");

    for (String arg: args)
    {
        String url = databasesProperties.get (arg + ".url");
        String user = databasesProperties.get (arg + ".user");
        String password= databasesProperties.get (arg + ".password");
        String table = databasesProperties.get (arg + ".table");

        String columnPrefix = arg + ".column."
        Map <String, String> columns = new HashMap <String, String> ();
        for (String key: databasesProperties.stringPropertyNames ())
        {
            if (key.startsWith (columnPrefix))
                columns.put (
                    key.substring (columnPrefix.length ()), 
                    databasesProperties.get (key));
        }

        doInsert (url, user, password, table, columns);
    }
}
```

Later you can always add more tables into your `databases.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Mikhail. But in this case you are assuming, column will only be two? But in reality columns can differ a lot. Some table will have 10 columns and some will have 20 columns.

Comment: @FarhanJama Covered case when set of columns may vary from table to table

Answer (score 0):

Save your Database properties in a class file `DBPropery.java`.

```
final class DBProperty
{
    static String[]  urls = {
                        "C",
                        "R",
                        "V"
                    }; //You can add more URLs here.
    static String[] driver= {
                        "Driver1",
                        "Driver2",
                        "Driver3"
                    };//You can add more drivers string
    static String[]  table = {
                        "Table1",
                        "Table2",
                        "Table3"
                    };//You can add more table names here According to URLs mentioned in urls array.
    static String[]  user = {
                        "A",
                        "P",
                        "T"
                    };//You can add more user names here according to URls mentioned in urls array.
    static String[]  pwd = {
                        "B",
                        "Q",
                        "U"
                    };//You can add more Password here according to URls mentioned in urls array.
    static String[] queries = {
                        "Query for Table1",
                        "Query for Table2",
                        "Query for Table3",
                    };//You can add more queries here for more tables according to URls mentioned in urls array.
    static int[]  columns ={
                        2,
                        2,
                        2
                    };//You can change the column numbers according to need . 0th index belongs to Table1 , 1 to table2....so on. 
                      //If you add more tables , add corresponding columns count to next index.
    static String[] columnValues ={
                                "1^John",
                                "34^Vicky",
                                "65^Ethen"
                            };//String at each index represents a row in corresponding table in table[] array. each column is seperated by delimiter "^".
}
```

Make all Changes in `DBProperty.java` file.
Then proceed with following class file

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
class MultiTableInsert implements Runnable
{
    Map<String,Integer> columnsInTable;
    Map<String,String>  tableDriver;
    Map<String,String>  rowForTable;
    Map<String,String>  queryForTable;
    Map<String,String>  urlForTable;
    Map<String,String>  userForTable;
    Map<String,String>  pwdForTable;
    String[]                tables ;
    public MultiTableInsert(String... tables)//Loading all Database Settings here..
    {
        this.tables = tables;
        columnsInTable  = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        rowForTable = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        tableDriver = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        urlForTable = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        userForTable= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        pwdForTable = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>(); 
        for (int i = 0 ; i < DBProperty.urls.length ; i++ )
        {
            try
            {
                tableDriver.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.driver[i]);
                queryForTable.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.queries[i]);
                columnsInTable.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.columns[i]);
                rowForTable.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.columnValues[i]);
                urlForTable.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.urls[i]);
                userForTable.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.user[i]);
                pwdForTable.put(DBProperty.table[i],DBProperty.pwd[i]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        insertIntoTable(tables);
    }
    private void insertIntoTable(String... tables)
    {
        for (String tble : tables )
        {
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
            try
            {
                Class.forName(tableDriver.get(tble));
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlForTable.get(tble),userForTable.get(tble),pwdForTable.get(tble)); 
                pStmt = con.prepareStatement(queryForTable.get(tble));
                int columns = columnsInTable.get(tble);
                String sRow = rowForTable.get(tble);
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sRow,"^");
                for (int i = 0; i < columns ; i++)
                {
                    pStmt.setString(i+1,(String)tokenizer.nextElement());
                }
                pStmt.execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    con.close();
                }catch (Exception ex){}
                try
                {
                    pStmt.close();
                }catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int length = args.length;
        int THREAD_COUNTS = 10;//Number of threads you want to start.
        switch (length)
        {
            case 0: 
                    System.out.println("Usage: javac MultiTableInsert Table1/Table2/Table3 <Table1/Table2/Table3> <Table1/Table2/Table3>");
                    System.exit(0);
            case 1:
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < THREAD_COUNTS ; i++)
                    {
                        MultiTableInsert mti = new MultiTableInsert(args[0]);
                        Thread th = new Thread(mti,"Thread"+i);//Create New Thread
                        th.start();                             //Start Thread
                    }
                    break;
            case 2:
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < THREAD_COUNTS ; i++)
                    {
                        MultiTableInsert mti = new MultiTableInsert(args[0],args[1]);//Create New Thread 
                        Thread th = new Thread(mti,"Thread"+i);                      //Start Thread     
                        th.start();
                    }
                    break;
            default:
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < THREAD_COUNTS ; i++)
                    {
                        MultiTableInsert mti = new MultiTableInsert(args[0],args[1],args[2]);//Create New Thread 
                        Thread th = new Thread(mti,"Thread"+i);                              //Start Thread     
                        th.start();
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @FarhanJamal I have updated the code with Threads . Have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for the help. I am again stuck with another problem and this time I believe it is more challenging. This is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047943/execute-select-sql-by-randomly-picking-tables). If you have some free time, any suggestions will be of great help. Thanks in advance.