# Execute SELECT sql by randomly picking tables

Tags: java, database, multithreading, random, executorservice

I am working on a project in which I have two tables in a different database with different schemas. So that means I have two different connection parameters for those two tables to connect using JDBC-

Let's suppose below is the `config.property` file-

```
TABLES: table1 table2

#For Table1
table1.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/garden
table1.user: gardener
table1.password: shavel
table1.driver: jdbc-driver
table1.percentage: 80



#For Table2
table2.url: jdbc:mysql://otherhost:3306/forest
table2.user: forester
table2.password: axe
table2.driver: jdbc-driver
table2.percentage: 20
```

Below method will read the above `config.property file` and make a `ReadTableConnectionInfo object` for each tables.

```
private static HashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo> tableList = new HashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo>();

private static void readPropertyFile() throws IOException {

    prop.load(Read.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    tableNames = Arrays.asList(prop.getProperty("TABLES").split(" "));

    for (String arg : tableNames) {

        ReadTableConnectionInfo ci = new ReadTableConnectionInfo();

        String url = prop.getProperty(arg + ".url");
        String user = prop.getProperty(arg + ".user");
        String password = prop.getProperty(arg + ".password");
        String driver = prop.getProperty(arg + ".driver");
        double percentage = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty(arg + ".percentage"));

        ci.setUrl(url);
        ci.setUser(user);
        ci.setPassword(password);
        ci.setDriver(driver);
        ci.setPercentage(percentage);

        tableList.put(arg, ci);
    }

}
```

Below is the `ReadTableConnectionInfo` class that will hold all the table connection info for a particular table.

```
public class ReadTableConnectionInfo {

    public String url;
    public String user;
    public String password;
    public String driver;
    public String percentage;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(String driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public double getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(double percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }
}
```

Now I am creating ExecutorService for specified number of threads and passing this `tableList object` to constructor of `ReadTask` class-

```
        // create thread pool with given size
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            service.submit(new ReadTask(tableList));
        }
```

Below is my `ReadTask` that implements `Runnable interface` in which each thread is supposed to make a connection for each tables.

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {

    private final HashMap<String, XMPReadTableConnectionInfo> tableLists;

public ReadTask(HashMap<String, ReadTableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
    this.tableLists = tableList;
}


@Override
public void run() {

    int j = 0;
    dbConnection = new Connection[tableLists.size()];
    statement = new Statement[tableLists.size()];

    //loop around the map values and make the connection list
    for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {

        dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(ci.getUrl(), ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(), ci.getDriver());
        statement[j] = dbConnection[j].createStatement();

        j++;
    }

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= 60 minutes) {

    /* Generate random number and check to see whether that random number
     * falls between 1 and 80, if yes, then choose table1
     * and then use table1 connection and statement that I made above and do a SELECT * on that table.
     * If that random numbers falls between 81 and 100 then choose table2 
     * and then use table2 connection and statement and do a SELECT * on that table
     */

    ResultSet rs = statement[what_table_statement].executeQuery(selectTableSQL);

    }
     }
}
```

Currently I have two tables, that means each thread will make two connections for each table and then use that particular table connection for doing SELECT * on that table depending on the random generation number.

**Algorithm:-**

1. Generate Random number between 1 and 100.
2. If that random number is less than `table1.getPercentage()` then choose `table1`
   and then use `table1 statement object` to make a `SELECT sql call` to that database.
3. else choose `table2` and then use `table2 statement object` to make a `SELECT sql call` to that database.

**My Question-**

I am having hard time in figuring out how should apply the above algorithm and how should I compare the `random number` with each `tables percentage` and then decide which table I need to use and after that figure out which `table connection and statements` I need to use to make a `SELECT sql call`.

So that means I need to check `getPercentage()` method of each table and them compare with the Random Number.

Right now I have only two tables, in future I can have three tables, with percentage distribution might be as `80 10 10`.

**UPDATE:-**

```
class ReadTask implements Runnable {

    private Connection[] dbConnection = null;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<ReadTableConnectionInfo, Connection> tableStatement = new ConcurrentHashMap<ReadTableConnectionInfo, Connection>();

    public ReadTask(LinkedHashMap<String, XMPReadTableConnectionInfo> tableList) {
        this.tableLists = tableList;
    }


    @Override
    public run() {

    int j = 0;
    dbConnection = new Connection[tableLists.size()];

    //loop around the map values and make the connection list
    for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {

    dbConnection[j] = getDBConnection(ci.getUrl(), ci.getUser(), ci.getPassword(), ci.getDriver());
    tableStatement.putIfAbsent(ci, dbConnection[j]);

    j++;
    }

      Random random = new SecureRandom();

      while ( < 60 minutes) {

        double randomNumber = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
        ReadTableConnectionInfo table = selectRandomConnection(randomNumber);

        for (Map.Entry<ReadTableConnectionInfo, Connection> entry : tableStatement.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getKey().getTableName().equals(table.getTableName())) {

                final String id = generateRandomId(random);
                final String selectSql = generateRandomSQL(table);

                preparedStatement = entry.getValue().prepareCall(selectSql);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, id);

                rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            }
        }
      }
    }



        private String generateRandomSQL(ReadTableConnectionInfo table) {

        int rNumber = random.nextInt(table.getColumns().size());

        List<String> shuffledColumns = new ArrayList<String>(table.getColumns());
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledColumns);

        String columnsList = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < rNumber; i++) {
            columnsList += ("," + shuffledColumns.get(i));
        }

        final String sql = "SELECT ID" + columnsList + "  from "
                + table.getTableName() + " where id = ?";

        return sql;
    }


    private ReadTableConnectionInfo selectRandomConnection(double randomNumber) {

        double limit = 0;
        for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {
            limit += ci.getPercentage();
            if (random.nextDouble() < limit) {
                return ci;
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of it as a loop over the available connections, something like the following:

```
public run() {
  ...
  Random random = new SecureRandom();

  while ( < 60 minutes) {
    double randomNumber = random.nextDouble() * 100.0;
    ReadTableConnectionInfo tableInfo = selectRandomConnection(randomNumber);

    // do query...
  }
}


private ReadTableConnectionInfo selectRandomConnection(double randomNumber) {
  double limit = 0;
  for (ReadTableConnectionInfo ci : tableLists.values()) {
    limit += ci.getPercentage();
    if (randomNumber < limit) {
      return ci;
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

As long as randomNumber has a maximum value of less then sum(percentage), that'll do the job.

One other thing I thought of: if you're going to end up having so many possible queries that the a looping lookup becomes an issue, you could build a lookup table:  create an array such that the total size of the array contains enough entries so that the relative weightings of the queries can be represented with integers.

For your example of three queries, 80:10:10, have a 10-entry array of `ReadTableConnectionInfo` with eight references pointing to table1, one to table2, and one to table3.  Then simply scale your random number to be `0 <= rand < 10` (eg  `(int)(Math.random() * 10)`, and use it to index in to your array.

Comment: Thanks sharakan for the suggestion. I just updated my question by modifying your code slightly. Let me know that is also fine or not. And regarding your lookup table. I will try to see whether it is becoming bottleneck or not.

Comment: No, that won't work.  1) nextRandom() generates a new Random number each time  you call it. 2) nextRandom() returns a number from [0..1), you need to scale it if your 'limit' values are going to be from [0..100).  3) You should create the Random object once, and then use it repeatedly, don't recreate it each time.  Take a look at the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble()

Comment: I think I got confused with the way you posted out your code. Can you tell me in your code from where you are getting the `randomNumber value`? It will also be of great help if you can provide the actual flow in your code basis on my code. Then I can understand the flow properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a chunk from your code, showing the hook to my function.  Main thing to remember about `Random` is that it's really a sequence of random numbers.  You create the sequence once, and then move through it to iterate through the random numbers.

Comment: Thanks sharakan for the suggestion. I totally forgot about that creating Random object only once. Thanks for reminding me about that.

Comment: There is one more problem in the same question. Currently we have find out the table that we will be using for doing `SELECT SQL`. Now I need to figure it out which corresponding table `STATEMENT object` I should use here. As currently if you take a look into my code , `Statement object is an array of statements` so how I should figure it out from that array, this table statement object is this particular statement. So that I can simply execute `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);`

Comment: You could do that in a bunch of ways.  Most straightforward is to make change those arrays to `Map<ReadTableConnectionInfo, ...>` where ... is either a `Connection` or a `Statement`.  Then you can use the function I described to select a `ReadTableConnectionInfo`, and then look up the other objects in those maps.  That might be a good first step, but then I would refactor that further so that you have a single object composed of the `Statement` and `Connection`, which can execute the query, and the random lookup function looks up those instead of `ReadTableConnectionInfo` instances.

Comment: Thanks a lot sharakan for the help. I just tried your suggestion. I have updated my code as well. Can you please take a look and let me know if there are any thread safety issues there? Or it looks good.. Since you have the context what I am trying to do. I believe you can help me out here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no shared state between threads, and so there should be no thread safety issues.  I think at this point though you'd benefit by posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a more complete workthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how many tables you have, their percentages will always add up to 100. The easiest way to conceptualize how you would choose is to think of each table as representing a range of percentages.

For instance, with three tables that have the percents you mentioned (80%, 10%, 10%), you could conceptualize them as:

Random Number 
  From       To    == Table ==
0.0000   0.8000    Table_1
0.8000   0.9000    Table_2
0.9000   1.0000    Table_3

So, generate a Random # between 0.0000 and 1.0000 and then go down the ordered list and see which range fits, and therefore which table to use.

(BTW: I'm not sure why you have *two* connections for each table.)

Comment: Thanks Darius. Whatever you posted, I already know about that like I need to generate random number etc etc. Only thing I am not able to understand how to make all those things work together in the code. And regarding your question of why I have two connections for each table. Because by random number generation, it might be possible that I need to work on Table1 or Table2, so I need to do select on either of these tables basis on what table gets picked and that is the reason two connections.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a lookup table which contains the table name and its weight:

```
class LookupTable {
    private int[]    weights;
    private String[] tables;
    private int      size = 0;

    public LookupTable(int n) {
        this.weights = new int[n];
        this.tables = new String[n];
    }

    public void addTable(String tableName, int r) {
        this.weights[size] = r;
        this.tables[size] = tableName;
        size++;
    }

    public String lookupTable(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
            if (this.weights[i] >= n) {
                return this.tables[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code to initialize the table:

```
    LookupTable tr = new LookupTable(3);
    // make sure adds the range from lower to upper!
    tr.addTable("table1", 20);
    tr.addTable("table2", 80);
    tr.addTable("table3", 100);
```

The test code:

```
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // r.nextInt(101) + 1 would return a number of range [1~100]. 
        int n = r.nextInt(101) + 1;
        String tableName = tr.lookupTable(n);
        System.out.println(n + ":" + tableName);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ericson for the help. In my code, I already have `ReadTableConnectionInfo` class which will contain table information and its percentage(weight) so creating another class will make me to have lots of duplicate code.